# Problem while performing the BSE GW calculations in VASP

Tags: vasp, gw-bse

I am trying to learn the BSE GW calculations in VASP. Using the [procedure](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Dielectric_properties_of_Si_using_BSE) described on the VASP website.

I am stuck at the last step 5 (BSE calculation). I didn't get any error in the 5th step but calculations are not proceeding. Here I am adding the tail of output corresponding to 5th step:

```
LDA part: xc-table for Pade appr. of Perdew\
found WAVECAR, reading the header\
POSCAR, INCAR and KPOINTS ok, starting setup\
WARNING: small aliasing (wrap around) errors must be expected\
FFT: planning ...\
 reading WAVECAR\
 the WAVECAR file was read sucessfully\
 initial charge from wavefunction\
 the WAVEDER file was read successfully\
energies w=\

 responsefunction array rank= 176\
 allocating   0 responsefunctions rank=   176\
 allocating   0 responsefunctions rank=   176\
 Doing            0  frequencies in blocks of            0\
 allocating two-electron 4 orbital integral table   4   8   4   8\
 BSE (scaLAPACK) single prec attempting allocation of   0.019 Gbyte  rank=   6170\
 BSE setting up matrix\
 reading now WFULL0001.tmp\
 reading now WFULL0003.tmp\
 reading now WFULL0006.tmp\
 reading now WFULL0008.tmp\
 reading now WFULL0011.tmp\
 reading now WFULL0012.tmp\
 reading now WFULL0007.tmp\
 reading now WFULL0015.tmp\
| reading now WFULL0005.tmp\
 reading now WFULL0014.tmp\
 reading now WFULL0016.tmp\
 reading now WFULL0009.tmp\
 reading now WFULL0002.tmp\
 reading now WFULL0004.tmp\
.reading now WFULL0010.tmp\
........|......... BSE redistributing all elements\

 BSE diagonalizing matrix (scaLAPACKaware)\
 BSE calculating oscillator strength\
```

After this, calculations are not proceeding. I tried with some other settings as well and tried many attempts but nothing works out. If someone is familiar with these calculations, please suggest.

Comment: Seems the calculation is done. Can you find the section of 'opticaltransitions' in vasprun.xml?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.                                                                                       yes, I searched in the vasprun.xml file of the 5th step, this 'opticaltransitions'  section is present.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if you've made any progress on this in the last 6+ months? Please update us if you found the answer!

Comment: I am not aware why the 5th step is not working, but as per suggestion, I check out that 'opticaltransitions' is present in vasprun.xml.

Comment: I tried this for the Si system. For another system, I tried and still had the same problem. This time also 5th step was not working and I didn't find this time 'opticaltransitions' tag.

Comment: @XiaomingWang I'm not sure if you saw the response because you weren't "pinged", but since the answer was "yes" do you think the calculation is done? Perhaps you could write an answer to this question to that effect? It would be really nice to get this out of the review queue now that we have 300+ questions in that queue!

Comment: Dear Expert and all,                                                                                                             If anyone has any ideas, please suggest. I am trying GW BSE calculations in which the 5th step is not working. I tried to perform the calculations with more number of processors but still not working.

Comment: Did you find an answer? Are you still actively looking for an answer? Please update us!